# How make GeoServer and leafLet secure in a web applciation

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, security, leaflet, geoserver

I am developing a website and using leafLet for visualization. Data are coming from a database and everything works fine.

I developed something like this:
https://maps.gcc.tas.gov.au/dogexerciseareas.html

As you can see, if you do a right-click on the page and select ViewSource, you can see the servername, port, and database (`typeName : 'GCC_cc:DogExerciseAreas',`). To me, this is not very secure especially if we host everything (IIS, DB, GeoServer,..), So, Is there any way to hide these details at the client side and make this more secure.

Comment: Use a proxy, and let it handle the auth details.

Comment: Ivan could you please explain more, Yes, I have seen some people suggested to use Proxy to have them on the same port, but I never tried that, Does it hide these settings?

Comment: Change your layer name so it is different to your layer name? servername and port tend to be public knowledge so people can see your map

Comment: Good argument Ian, Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Well, I had a chance to work on this for a long time and I came up with this approach"

First: Put Geoserver in one VPC zone and only allows access to it from specific IP and port (i.e. Isolate from the world expect specific IP and port)

Second: As @IvanSanchez has suggested.use proxy and urlredirect to interact with Geoserver via web server (not client)

With the above, everything goes through web-server, then passed to Geoserver.