# How to authorize accessing the geoserver layers

Tags: security, iis-7, leaflet, webserver, geoserver

No issue with using url rewrite to hide the GeoServer, and no issue to limit accessing the GeoServer from web server by firewall, therefore no issue with authentication. The question is :

**How shall I authorize accessing to the layers from web server?**

I would like to limit accessing the layers to specific group of users. All of the calls (wms,..) come from the client side (requests come from Leaflet through web server and then passed to the GeoServer). Is there any sample code/approach that allows me to control accessing the layers with the username who is viewing the website? Or alternatively, how can I send the request to the GeoServer from the server (IIS) side not the client side (Leaflet)? Without doing this, users can change the layer name and see the layers which are not supposed to if they know the name of the layer.

I am using Leaflet, IIS, and Psql.

This is an extent of this question [How make GeoServer and leafLet secure in a web applciation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44640905/how-make-geoserver-and-leaflet-secure-in-a-web-applciation)

Comment: You didn't say what authentication was used yet. How did you check the request came from a valid "user"? That's called authentication, not authorization.

Comment: Since the request can only come through IIS, so IIS is responsible for authentication and since the infrastructure has firewall and Route 53 (AWS) Geoserver only serves request which came from IIS. So no need for additional authentication inside geoserver as authentication is done by two powerful tools (IIS and Firewall (Route 53)). This was about authentication. So, my issue is authorization. Is there any way to send the request from server side and get the response at the client side? In all the examples of leaflet, the request to the GeoServer was sent from the client side.

Comment: Unfortunately, IIS cannot. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/ The built-in authentication methods each map incoming requests to Windows/AD user accounts in a different way. So you need to choose one of them, or develop your own forms authentication, or use any OAuth based. Once requests can be mapped to user accounts, you can then perform authorization accordingly. I know you want to restrict server access via network, but usually that's not enough.

Comment: Thank you @LexLi, Does this mean that the admin needs to create two accounts one at GeoServer and One at IIS? This is not an easy option, What other options do I have? what about calling the GeoServer API and create a user account there when an admin create an IIS account? I have not tried it yet. just a guess, Maybe sth like this http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/geofence-server/rest-userrole.html

Answer (score 2):

You can configure GeoServer to use your Active Directory users and roles to provide authentication to layers of your WMS. This [tutorial](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/security/tutorials/activedirectory/index.html) in the documentation will take you through the steps needed.

There are a number of [related questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/authentication+geoserver) on gis.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I thought I have replied to your answer!, thank you Ian, So,I can path credentials to geosever by .../geoserver/wms?...&user=??&password=??. If I put them in the leaflet, everybody sees them, How can I hide this at the server side in IIS? All the examples (with leaflet) need the wms call to be done at the client side. The other issue might be a need for adding a username in two different times/location (one at the IIS and one at the Geoserver, if these two are not part of the AD domain, however, I think I can solve this by Geoserver API or some other techniques)